# Invalid assertion for overflow check Frama-C

Tags: static-analysis, frama-c

While checking the overflow for `short` and `char` data type for add operation, the assertions inserted by Frama-C are seems to be incorrect:

[image]

For char and short data the maximum positive and negative values are of integer data type.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integral types of rank less than `int` are converted to either `int` or `unsigned` when used in an arithmetic operation (see C11 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions). This is why you see the cast to `(int)` for `x` and `y`. Note that by default `-rte` will not emit warning for downcasts, as they are not undefined behavior (6.3.1.3§3 indicates that signed downcasts are implementation defined and that an implementation may raise a signal). If you add the option `-warn-signed-downcast`, you'll see the assertions you were probably looking for, which are due to the cast into `(char)` of the result:

```
/*@ assert rte: signed_downcast: (int)x+(int)y ≤ 127; */
/*@ assert rte: signed_downcast: -128 ≤ (int)x+(int)y; */
```

Note that if you store the result into an int, as in

```
void main(void) {
    char x;
    char y;
    int z;
    x = 1;
    y = 127;
    z = x + y;
    return;
}
```

There won't be any downcast warning (but the signed overflow warnings will be present).